# time complexity of javascript method CharCodeAt()

Tags: javascript

Can anyone provide an answer or documentation on the time complexity of CharCodeAt() for javascript. I attempted to use this in a solution and I want to know if this hurts my algorithm's run time. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**It is O(1).**

As first the character is looked up using the index in the array. After that the corresponding character code can also be picked up using O(1) using something like a hashmap.

Comment: Can you provide any references?